# Wrapper for belongsTo returns null

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

2 tables - client and client_status
Table `client`:

```
id
client_status_id
name
```

This table contains 1 record with client_status_id and name filled.

Table `client_status`:

```
id
name
```

This table also not empty

Models for these tables:

```
class Client extends Model {
    public function status() {
        return $this->belongsTo(ClientStatus::class);
    }
}
```

and

```
class ClientStatus extends Model {
    protected $table = 'client_status';

    public function clients() {
        return $this->hasMany(Client::class);
    }
}
```

When I assign $client somewhere in ClientController:

- `$client->name` contains real client name
- `$client->status == null`, so, I can't get `$client->status->name` (name of client status). Why and how to change?

Answer (score 0):

The relationship is wrong, the user must have the status as has one, and the status belongs to user.

also from my opinion i would rather to save the user id, in the status table better. and it'll be much simple.

Comment: You are wrong from theoretical point of view - one client status can has many clients. For example, "Active client" status can has 10+ clients (hasMany), and from client side: one client can has just one status (belongsTo). The same described in Eloquent chapter of documentation

Comment: Sorry i miss understand the idea at the beginning, i thought that each user has one status for him. Try to do it like:
return $this->belongsTo('App\ClientStatus','client_status_id','id');

Comment: Last thought is great - everything works! Thanks, Ahmed